# How can I convert a separate column text into row using Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing

I am teaching myself machine learning and working on some dataset which have the columns

[image: dataframe image]
`

there are two sentences columns sent0 and sent1 and sol contains whether sent0 is against commonsense or sent1. If sent0 is against commonsense there is 0 in sol column.

What I want is to combine both sent0 and sent1 in one column as

[image: target dataframe]

Now if a sent0 is against commonsense i want to write it as 0 in sol column and 1 if sentence is right. I tried different ways but failed until now

Comment: How does one know whether `sent1` is commonsense or not, if `sol` only indicates this for `sent0`?

Comment: Hi Philip, in first dataframe sol indicates that first two of sent0 is against common sense by specifying in sol column, sol actually indicates that weather sent0 is against common sense or sent1. But in second dataframe i want to change it to 0 or 1 if sent0 is against commonsense than sol will be 0 if its alright than sol is 1.

Comment: Ah right, I got it. Let me think of something

Comment: yeah man, I am super stressed now. Need help badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
df = pd.DataFrame() # this should be your original df

import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id", "sent", "sol"])
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    id_ = row["id"]
    sent0 = row["sent0"]
    sent1 = row["sent1"]
    sol = row["sol"]

    # calculate solutions
    if sol == 0:    # if sent0 is against common sense
        sol0 = 0
        sol1 = 1    # is common sense
    else:
        sol0 = 1    # is common sense
        sol1 = 0

    columns = ["id", "sent", "sol"]
    data = data.append(pd.DataFrame([[id_, sent0, sol0]], columns=columns))
    data = data.append(pd.DataFrame([[id_, sent1, sol1]], columns=columns))
```

Comment: data.head() is returning only column names, seems like nothing is appending in it. I am debugging it, you can also check in dry run if you could find something you are missing

Comment: Yes, I edited the code- `data.append()` returns a new `DataFrame` and does not perform inplace appending

Comment: Hi Philipp I appreciate your afforts but it is not working either, it produces a lot of nan rows and a new unknown column with text data

Comment: Alright, I edited it again tested it with a dataframe I made in the console. This should finally work. Please do not forget to accept the answer.